# EXCEL VBA Macro: Can this be simplified using Range?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub NewPortName ()
      If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 7).Value = "RJ45" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Cells(16, 3).Value = "PCI-" +      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment details").Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 13), 7)

      ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 7).Value = "LC-LC" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Cells(16, 3).Value = "PFI-" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment details").Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 13), 10) + ":" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 36) + " to " + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 14), 10) + ":" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(2, 38)
      End If
      If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 7).Value = "RJ45" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Cells(17, 3).Value = "PCI-" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment details").Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 13), 7)

      ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 7).Value = "LC-LC" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Cells(17, 3).Value = "PFI-" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment details").Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 13), 10) + ":" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 36) + " to " + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 14), 10) + ":" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(3, 38)
      End If

End sub
```

I am currently modifying this line by line for individual cells due to the nature of the output over several ranges.

I am wondering if this can be simplified using Range, Two of the ranges in question out of 7 are `(M2:M100)` and `(N2:N100)`

I will need to repeat this code and change the cells individually over 700 times to reflect 700 individual cells if I can't make this abstract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, Esh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, cr
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String

    Set sh = Sheets("PAR Form")
    Set ws = Sheets("PAR_import")
    Set Esh = Sheets("Equipment details")

    s1 = "RJ45"
    s2 = "LC-LC"
    s3 = Esh.Cells(4, 4).Value

    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "G"), .Cells(Rws, "G"))
    End With

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        cr = c.Row
        If c = s1 Then
            ws.Cells(cr + 14, 3).Value = "PCI-" + s3 + "-" + Left(sh.Cells(cr, 13), 7)
        ElseIf c = s2 Then
            ws.Cells(cr + 14, 3).Value = "PFI-" + s3 + "-" + Left(sh.Cells(cr, 13), 10) + ":" + sh.Cells(cr, 36) + " to " + Left(sh.Cells(cr, 14), 10) + ":" + sh.Cells(cr, 38)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks, I am assuming that if i need to apply this to another range i will just need to make a new sub for every range ?

Comment: Very impressive code far above my belt, reading help files Ive managed to figure out about 80% but i cant get my head around how your referencing M2:m100 from    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "G"), .Cells(Rws, "G"))   and how i can change that for my next ranges.

Comment: Apologies really new to this here learning a lot from you guys, i gathered that was the column my problem is I’m trying to figure out how it is represented laid out in the Array, so that i can point to  and reference the following ranges)..  i have reformatted my dataset in sh in order to correctly extract the data, for import elsewhere,.    I want to Loop through (sh M2:M36 and output to ws c16:50), then Loop through (sh N2:M36 output to ws a51:a84) then (sh p2:q36 to ws c51:c84) and so on.

Comment: I downloaded your WB, I don't see anywhere the code you provided or the code I provided. When supplying a sample workbook, you should also show the desired result as well.

Comment: Hi its in module PARImport right at the bottom Last Sub NewPortName,

Comment: The Desired results is on PAR_import  c16:50 and a51:a84 and  c51:c84

Answer (score 0):

You could always try a loop along the lines of the below:

```
Sub ing()
For i = 2 To 100

  Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(i, 7).Value
  Case "RJ45"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Cells(i + 14, 3).Value = "PCI-" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment details").Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(i, 13), 7)
  Case "LC-LC"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Cells(i + 14, 3).Value = "PFI-" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment details").Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(i, 13), 10) + ":" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(i, 36) + " to " + Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(i, 14), 10) + ":" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR Form").Cells(i, 38)
  End Select
Next i
End Sub
```